# Extracting vector from embedded list in R

Tags: r

This feels like it should be easy, but I can't work it out. I have a list of lists, in the same form as below (but much, much, longer ...)

```
mylist <- list(list(x=c(1,2,3),y=4), 
            list(x=c(4,5,6,7),y=8), 
            list(x=c(1,2),y=6))
```

I want to extract a vector of the "y" values, ie c(4,8,6). Do you know how to do this? I have tried searching to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: `y <- sapply(mylist, function(x) x[["y"]])`

Answer (score 3):

Or using `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
map_dbl(mylist, "y")
#[1] 4 8 6
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to iterate over each item of `mylist` and retrieve only the "y" values. Easy with `sapply`:

```
sapply(mylist, '[[', 'y')

[1] 4 8 6
```